# How to set tracking link for order in magento from csv

Tags: php, magento, csv

I have csv which contain tracking number, tracking link, carrier code, order number. I am able to set tracking number, carrier code to particular order but not able to set tracking URL for the same order. please suggest me some code snippets or any way to solve this query.

```
if (($handle = fopen("".$webshopimport_path."\\CSV\\trackandtrace.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        Mage::init();
        $comment = null;
        $email = false;
        $includeComment = false;
        $orderId = '100000065';                                                        //get ordernumber from csv
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
        $convertor = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_order');
        $shipment = $convertor->toShipment($order);

        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem)
        {
            if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                continue;
            }
            $item = $convertor->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem);
            $qty = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
            $item->setQty($qty);
            $shipment->addItem($item);
        }

        $trackdata = array();
        $trackdata['carrier_code'] = $data[2];   //get carrier_code from csv
        $trackdata['title'] = $data[2];          //get title from csv
        $trackdata['number'] = $data[3];         //get track number from csv


        $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->addData($trackdata);

        $shipment->addTrack($track);

        Mage::register('current_shipment', $shipment);

        $shipment->register();
        $shipment->addComment($comment, $email && $includeComment);
        $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
        $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
            ->addObject($shipment)
            ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
            ->save();

        $shipment->sendEmail($email, ($includeComment ? $comment : ''));
    }
    fclose($handle);
    $retVar = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to set any tracking URL for orders because tracking URL are automatically generated with the order tracking number and the shipping service tracking URL structure.

For exemple, UPS tracking URL is : http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums={tracking_number}